# .htaccess and multiple unintended redirects

Tags: .htaccess

I have recently detected through https://httpstatus.io/ that our .htaccess file while working is causing a double redirect where a single redirect should only be necessary. We are redirecting pages from our old website http://www.gaconsulting.co.kr to our new website which is in a subdirectory at http://www.gaconsulting.co.kr/au/

I would greatly appreciate any advice anyone can provide into how to modify the existing .htaccess to minimize it to a single redirect.

The .htaccess contents are below:

```
<IfModule mod_substitute.c>
SubstituteMaxLineLength 10M
</IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cssmenu/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/easybox/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/etc/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fck/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/greybox/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/inc/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/includes/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jmenucss/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mail/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/member/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/menujs/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myform/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/popeye_css/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/popeye_lib/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Scripts/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/style/?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.gaconsulting.co.kr/au/ [R=301,L]
# Disable the server signature 
ServerSignature Off
```

Answer (score 0):

That rule will never redirect, since all `RewriteCond`s need to match. Something else on your server is causing the double redirect.